# Where should I release static local and global variable with ARC?

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, static, automatic-ref-counting

I just created a new class in my project, subclass of UITableViewController and noticed that in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: template, Apple still provide a static local NSString to use as a cell identifier.

I know that for static global/local variable we need to assign nil cause it's considered as strong.

So I asked myself the question : Where should I assign nil to static global variable ?
And static global variable ?

Thanks for the answers guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer to the "where should static global variables be released" is "nowhere".

Long answer goes like this: when you make a variable `static` or global, you want it to exist regardless of any instances of your classes coming into existence or being released. Simply speaking, you want your `static`s to always be there for you. Therefore, the only reason to release them would be if your program is about to exit. But if your program is exiting anyway, you might as well let the operating system handle the cleanup for you, and forget about releasing your global and static variables.

Note, however, that the use of `static` and global variables should be an exception, not a norm. You use them for a good reason, and exercise your best judgement to decide what should be `static`. Moreover, you should avoid referencing collections of non-static variables from static ones through a strong reference, because otherwise you may create hard-to-find memory leaks.

There is nothing wrong with a static local for the `NSString` used as your cell identifier: it takes very little memory, and it does not grow, so it's not a big deal that it is not released at the end of your program's run.

Comment: and in the case of global or local static it won't prevent my tableView from being deallocated ?

Comment: @Dabrut Not unless that global or static references your `tableView`, directly or indirectly. Your `tableView`, on the other hand, is allowed to have as many statics or globals in its implementation: as long as the reference to your view is not stored in one of them, instances of your table view can come and go as they please.

Comment: sorry for the confusion I meant my UITableViewController rather than my uitableview

Comment: @Dabrut Same deal: a presence of a static variable, inside or outside a method, does not prevent instances of a corresponding object from being released, except when the variable points to one of the instances, and is also a `__strong` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it, it will never be released and its ok since it is a global.

In ARC will be treated as strong for default and its lifetime it is equal to the application lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

Static strings are a special case, and don't need to be released.

Answer (score 0):

static variable, means it holds a strong reference to the object it points to.

```
static MyClass *var;
var = [MyClass instance];
```

Now `var` always holds strong reference to the above allocated object.so it will never be removed from memory.

But after some condition you no longer need that object,then simply
`var =nil` would work.
because now `var` points to nil and no longer points to created object.so that object will be deleted from memory.